# Porting QT Android app to iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt

I am a QT developer and I want to port my app to an iOS.

Which tool is best to do this job? Is it even a possible to port from QT to iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIKit lighthouse](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/08/09/update-on-uikit-lighthouse-platform/) has a port of Qt for iOS till some degree.

Comment: good link, but I think I need to have an Mac OS X, and I was thinking if there is something for windows. Sorry that I haven't mentioned it before.

Comment: Officially you can't develop anything for iPhone without OS X. There are some illegal workarounds (install OS X on a virtual machine for example) but all of them are difficult to set up. You will still find tons of posts on this topic here or with google.

Comment: okay I'll mark it as a good answer, because it really is a good one. But I don't have access to Mac OS X. So anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just googled for "QT-iPhone" and [that's](http://www.qt-iphone.com/Introduction.html) the first link that I found

Comment: It's only a port of QtCore up to now.